# Python cx_Oracle Insert Timestamp With Milliseconds

Tags: python, oracle, datetime, timestamp, cx-oracle

I have read the posts:
[Insert TIMESTAMP with milliseconds in Oracle with cx_Oracle and Python 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52145119/insert-timestamp-with-milliseconds-in-oracle-with-cx-oracle-and-python-3-6) and
[sqlserver datetime to oracle timestamp problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37925387/sqlserver-datetime-to-oracle-timestamp-problems)
, but none of them solved my problem.

Because, column number of my Oracle table is more than one.

I have tested both above links(thanks to them). Yet, their efficiency are limited. Such as, if the column order of the timestamp column on Oracle table is not 1 then setting cursor.setinputsizes(cx_Oracle.TIMESTAMP) does not work.

According to Panagiotis Kanavos([sqlserver datetime to oracle timestamp problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37925387/sqlserver-datetime-to-oracle-timestamp-problems)):

```
ts = datetime.datetime.now()
cursor.prepare("INSERT INTO python_tstamps VALUES(:t_val)")

cursor.setinputsizes(t_val=cx_Oracle.TIMESTAMP)

cursor.execute(None, {'t_val':ts})
db.commit()
```

On the other hand, I have multiple records to insert like ~250k. So, I need to fetch all my data and convert to them into dictionary, and finally append that dictionary object to a list in order to use input object in executemany function.

```
column_name = ["instance_id", "record_id", "record_id1"]

dict1 = dict(zip(column_name,outputsql[0]))

for key in dict1:
    print(key)

t = []
t.append(dict1)
cursororacle.prepare("INSERT /*+ append */INTO schematest.test  VALUES (:instance_id, :record_id, :record_id1)")
cursororacle.setinputsizes(instance_id=cx_Oracle.TIMESTAMP, record_id=cx_Oracle.TIMESTAMP)
cursororacle.executemany(None, t)
```

Conveting 250k records is not efficient. Is there any other solution/s?

Edit: I want to insert my output data(outputsql) without dictionary conversion. Is it possible; if it is then how?

Thanks in advance!

Ps: outputsql is output of another db session query and it returns records with correct milliseconds precision.

```
cursorsql = connsql.cursor()
cursorsql.execute('select top 1  record_id, instance_id, record_id from dbo.recordlog  (nolock)')
outputsql = cursorsql.fetchall()
```

Comment: What actually is the question ?

Comment: Yes, please edit the post and give sample data to clarify what you want!  At the start you mention `cursor.setinputsizes(cx_Oracle.TIMESTAMP) ` works when you have one column, but later you show how to use it with multiple columns.   Other comments: don't use `prepare()`.  Instead just pass the SQL statement to `executemany()`.  Review the cx_Oracle documentation on using `executemany()` https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html

Comment: Thanks! I have edited. Like I mentioned before, converting outputsql to dictionary is not efficient, it's cost will be high for 250k records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to convert your data to dictionaries. The [documentation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/cursor.html#Cursor.setinputsizes) for `cursor.setinputsizes()` shows that you can pass either positional arguments or keyword arguments. So, if you need to indicate that the third column is supposed to be a timestamp, you can do the following:

```
cursor.setinputsizes(None, None, cx_Oracle.TIMESTAMP)
```

What this does is says that the first two binding positions can use the default binding. This will be determined by examining the data that is supplied when `cursor.execute()` or `cursor.executemany()` is called. The third binding position will be bound as a timestamp column.

I hope this is clear enough!